# Accessing the Global object in play! 2.0 with Java

Tags: java, playframework-2.0

I have extended the *GlobalSettings* class as shown in the tutorial [Application global settings](http://www.playframework.org/documentation/2.0/JavaGlobal).

How do I then gain access to the instance of this class, let's say from a view method?
I'm assuming that one instance was created when the application was started and that it is probably a member of some object.

I would have expected for example to find it here:

```
Play.application().getGlobalSettings()
```

or something similar, but I couldn't find it anywhere in the Play.* hierarchy.

Any ideas?
Thanks.

Answer (score 5):

I'm new to Play 2.0, however, I think you're better served by using plugin injection. Check this out:

https://github.com/typesafehub/play-plugins/tree/master/inject

Using this approach you simply add the following line to your controller (and some other configuration, as documented in the link above):

```
@Inject static MyStaticObj obj;
```

And all the rest is done automatically using the injection framework. No need to worry about global, etc.

That said, like you I spent a lot of time trying to figure out how to use the GlobalSettings object for this before discovering the plugin injection framework.

My sense is that given how Global is implemented (as class in the default/unnamed package) it's not possible to reference it anywhere in the application code. I'm not sure if this was by design or by accident (it seems that the Play folks are thinking about Scala quite a bit these days...). Fortunately the plugin approach seems to be better way to handle these shared globals.

Comment: Thanks, I wasn't even aware that there's such a thing as plugins for play... But since using this plugin I get a singleton pattern anyhow, why not just do it myself? What are the advantages of using this plugin over my own singleton implementation?

Answer (score -3):

Just reference the Global object directly. 
For example don't write :

```
public class Global extends GlobalSettings {}
```

write

```
object Global extends GlobalSettings {}
```

or

```
object Global extends Global {}
class Global extends GlobalSettings {}
```

and than you can reference Global object anywhere in your code just write :

```
Global.someMethod()
```

Comment: Is that scala? I don't know this form.. Does this mean that the instance is not available from any Play reference?

Comment: This is Scala code. I am not sure how exactly would you do this in Java.

Comment: Thanks, but I'm looking for a java solution, there are so many new things for me and so I rather to use as little scala as possible at the moment. For now I'm just using a *Singleton* pattern but I really wish to find a better solution.